# iOS: CF object leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code under **ARC**:

```
- (NSString*)encodeURL:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *anewString = (__bridge NSString *)(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding])));
    if (anewString) {
        return anewString;
    }
    return @"";
}
```

I analyzed this code and xcode gave me leak message.But I donnot know how to fix it.
Please help!Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` returns an **owned** object (retain count of +1). The `__bridge` cast bridges the CF object to Objective-C but does not transfer the ownership, so you create a memory leak because ARC does not know that the object is retained. Use `__bridge_transfer` instead of `_bridge` to transfer the ownership so that Objective-C ARC can take care it for you.

Comment: You can also use `CFBridgingRelease()`. It is identical to `__bridge_transfer` but may be easier for you to use correctly if you are accustomed to CF's memory management conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(__bridge NSString *)(...)` use `CFBridgingRelease( ... )`, where "..." = your string creation.